# Is it secure to store credentials protected with dotenv on public repos on Github?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, dotenv

I am using GitHub and upload Jupyter notebooks.
My goal is to showcase use cases of Cloud service providers like AWS, IBM or Heroku.

Therefore, I store user credentials on public repos on GitHub.
This allows me to execute the code on the Cloud platforms.

(Reacting to comments:
I am not storing the credentials on GitHub, but using the os.getenv function to get the SECRET_KEY from .env file stored locally, which is added to .git ignore. Sorry for being unclear.)

I am using dotenv to secure my credentials.

I am following the method described here:

[Keep your secrets safe with Python-dotenv](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-dotenv-module)

The implementation works fine, but I want to ascertain that this is a secure method to protect critical credentials against hacks, or do I miss something?

Comment: you just have the .env file in the repo right ?

Comment: But the methods described in your link is all about how NOT to store credentials protected with dotenv on public repos on github! The whole idea is that you keep your `.env` at home, and not store in on github. Thanks to the fact that it is in a dotenv, it separates the code, that doesn't contain hard-coded credentials, from the `.env`. The code is on github, the `.env` isn't. If you store the `.env` on github, you ruin the whole idea, and it is exactly the same as hard-coding credentials in your code and put the code on github.

Comment: @chrslg: .env is not on GitHub of course. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @LarsNielsen
.env file is only locally in the directory. 
It is not in the repo on GitHub and added to git ignore.

Comment: Oh. In that case, you don't store credentials on github. Then it is as safe as the place you store `.env`. If it is on your PC at home, then, sure, someone could break in and steal your PC, but I guess you are used to that kind of risk.

Comment: @chrslg
Thanks, this is the answer with reassurance.

Answer (score 2):

Security usually is a compromise between convinience and security level. What **you should not do** at least is **having credentials in code or version control**.

- credentials in a repo is a really bad practice, please avoid this specially for public repos and code for your company. dotenv is intended for having secrets locally in anycase, never adding them to a repo.
- credentials as pipeline varibales is OK. I used GitLab variables, and there is [something similar for github](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md) although I am not an expert on github. Just be sure to not log them, do make them protected and not visible (masked).
- the best option is to manage credentials in a more advanced service like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), so you can rotate them, deprecate them and have full control. Of course this solution is more advanced and requires integration.

Anyway, there may be always leaks, if you use third party machines for running actions/jobs you have potential security risks, so rotating credentials periodically is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks. A lot to think about in this answer.